# "I've not" vs. "I haven't" — is one preferred?

Tags: difference, usage, contractions

I sometimes see teens type:

> I've not...

Instead of typing:

> I haven't...

What can you say about it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Each is a different contraction for "**I have not**" - what is unclear?

Comment: Both are acceptable.  Neither is better than the other *in general*, although sometimes one will *sound* better in context, to emphasize the "have" or the "not".

Comment: This was covered on the [Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/difference-between-i-havent-and-ive-not-etc) site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been already stated, they are both contractions of "I have not," and neither is incorrect. In the USA, I would say that "I haven't" is far more commonly heard. The use of "I've not" sounds a bit more proper and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, just the difference in emphasis. If you want to emphasize the negative, don't contract *not* and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

They are equal. Neither is preferable. It is your choice, depending on which you like. A professional, like a speechwriter, might have a stronger preference based on more complex criteria, but for most people, there is no difference.

If you are feeling particularly bold, you might try

> I'ven't

Which is a contraction of "I have not". That one isn't "accepted", but most native speakers will understand the meaning, and some accents pronounce "I have not" close to "I've'nt".

Comment: Actually, because apostrophes in contractions replace missing letters, the correct spelling is "I'ven't." And this word, while maybe not incorrect, might raise some eyebrows, especially when used by a non-native speaker. I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: **I'ven't** might be used in creative writing to simulate the pronunciation of a particular English dialect, but it's not "correct" English and would not ordinarily appear in any other kind of writing.

Answer (score 0):

When I speaking English I think in my mind that's easier to pronounce the word NOT separately from the verb to be like are or is for example instead of I say you aren't most if the times I'd say you're not or it's not so to me it's preferable use I've not it's clearer I don't know why but I think I'm not saying the negative form when I use these contractions isn't, aren't or haven't

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! I'm sorry, but your answer is rather hard to follow; could you please [edit] it to add some punctuation?