# Is it ok to short words more than one time, like I'ven't?

Tags: contractions

Actually I have this question for long time. As I started to use contracted words like I've , it's, you're (verb with subject), and due to habit of shorting verb+not like haven't, isn't etc, eventually I came to write words that are contracted twice e.g I'ven't, it'sn't, you'ren't etc.

But I suspect about correctness of it since that I've never found such twice contraction in a sentence. So, finally I has come to ask: Is it ok to contract and combine more than one words simultaneously?

I mean combining effects of `I've + not` & `I + haven't` to `I'ven't`! and similar possible word contractions.

Comment: Set the way-back machine to question number 50 on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-a-word-be-contracted-twice-e-g-ivent

Comment: Generally, it's best not to make any more contractions. There are a certain number of accepted contractions in English, and that group nearly never grows outside of local dialects.

Comment: No, no and no. There are no double contractions. They are two choices sometimes, however: He isn't rich or He's not rich. Your examples are not correct. I've not seen him today (usually British); I haven't see him today (usually American). Just two examples.

Answer (score 5):

Contraction of *VERB+not* (*isn't*, *haven't*, &c) occurs only when the verb is stressed; but contraction of *NOUN+VERB* or *PRONOUN+VERB* (*Jack's*, *she'd*, *I've*, &c) occurs only when the verb is **un**stressed.

A verb can't be stressed and unstressed at the same time; so these “double” contractions are not valid English.

Comment: You've not pointed out that idiomatically, most people today would normally contract that one as *You **haven't** [pointed it out].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was trying to avoid opening that can of worms.

Comment: I hadn't seen [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/ive-not-vs-i-havent-is-one-preferred) when I posted that comment, but it might be worth you including a link to it. Though as implied above, I personally *don't* endorse the accepted answer there, which starts with *They are equal. Neither is preferable.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers And the accepted answer **proposes** *I'ven't*. rrr...

Answer (score -1):

No. There are specific words like 'not' or verbs 'is and 'have' come to mind, that contracted with a pronoun are fine in English usage. Your use of I'ven't isnt a word and isnt easily even interpreted meaningfully. It looks like 'I vent', with entirely different meaning.

Your combination of I have not must be I haven't. Anything other than that would not be standard English usage. Hope that helps you.

Comment: "Isnt" isn't a correct form.

Comment: What is your point, oh anonymous grammar god?